# recursive counting on c

Tags: c, recursion

Good Day! I have a problem on counting in recursion, this code is already in the net, but i did some addition code on it, my problem is how to count the IF part of the program? , this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int combinationUtil(int arr[], int data[], int start, int end, int index, int r,float MEAN);

int printCombination(int arr[], int n, int r,float MEAN)
{

int data[r];

combinationUtil(arr, data, 0, n-1, 0, r,MEAN);
}


int combinationUtil(int arr[], int data[], int start, int end, int index, int r,float MEAN)
{
int j,i,a=1,b=0,f=0,ch,total=0;
float sum=0,mean,deviation=0,standard_deviation;



if (index == r){
        int count=0;

    for (j=0; j<r; j++)
    {

       sum=sum+data[j];
        deviation=deviation+pow((MEAN-data[j]),2);
    }

   mean=sum/r;
   standard_deviation=sqrt(deviation/(r-1));

   if(MEAN<=(mean+(2.776*standard_deviation))&& MEAN>=(mean-(2.776*standard_deviation))){
    printf("%d",a); 
    count++;}
  else printf("%15d",b); 
  count=count;

   return ;}



 for (i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++)
  {

    data[index] = arr[i];
    combinationUtil(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r,MEAN);

  }

  }




int main()
{
int arr[] = {2,4,6,8,10,7,8};
int r = 3,i,count=1,total=0;
int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
float sum=0,MEAN;
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    sum=sum+arr[i];
}
MEAN=sum/n;
printf("MEAN=%f\n\n\n",MEAN);


printCombination(arr,n,r,MEAN));


return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: "code is already in the net". Huh?

Comment: "to count the IF part of the program" How do you count part of a program?

Comment: @Drop I guess OP meant he got the code from the internet.

Comment: @user3437460 Hm... good hypothesis.

Comment: i found difficulty on counting it, i use count++ but it did not work

Comment: that is what i mean , thank you for cosideration

Comment: The code formatting needs to be fixed. It's hard to know what's wrong with the code if it's impossible to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in order to count the IF segment, you should add the count variable as a reference parameter to the combinationUtil function, so you can get the result of the count out of the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int combinationUtil(int arr[], int data[], int start, int end, int index, int r, float MEAN, int *count);

int printCombination(int arr[], int n, int r,float MEAN, int *count)
{
    int *data = malloc(sizeof(int) * r);

    combinationUtil(arr, data, 0, n-1, 0, r,MEAN, count);

    free(data);
    return 0;
}


int combinationUtil(int arr[], int data[], int start, int end, int index, int r, float MEAN, int *count)
{
    int j, i, a=1, b=0, f=0, ch, total=0;
    float sum=0, mean, deviation=0, standard_deviation;

    if (index == r) {

        for (j=0; j<r; j++)
        {
             sum=sum+data[j];
                deviation=deviation+pow((MEAN-data[j]),2);
        }

        mean=sum/r;
        standard_deviation=sqrt(deviation/(r-1));

        if(MEAN<=(mean+(2.776*standard_deviation))
            && MEAN>=(mean-(2.776*standard_deviation))){

            printf("%d",a);
            (*count)++;
        }
        else
            printf("%15d",b);

        return 1; // different return value
    }

    for (i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++)
    {
        data[index] = arr[i];
        combinationUtil(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r,MEAN, count);
    }
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    int arr[] = {2,4,6,8,10,7,8};
    int r = 3, i, count=0, total=0;
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    float sum = 0, MEAN;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + arr[i];
    }
    MEAN = sum / n;
    printf("MEAN=%f\n\n\n",MEAN);

    printCombination(arr, n, r, MEAN, &count);

    printf("\ncount = %d", count);

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: code is complete and only in C not in C++.

Comment: That is if you want to get the count on the main function, otherwise you should be more specific.

Comment: sorry for tagging c++, i thought that c and c++ are somewhat the same so i also tag c++

Comment: @user3386109 you are correct, I didn't realize but it's the same principle.

In the function definition of combinationUtil you add the parameter: int *count
And when you need to count you use this: (*count)++;

Comment: @Artwo, the program will crashed, what should i do?

Comment: @user3386109, thank you for helping me, i will try your suggestion

Comment: @marchan the first time you call combinationUtil, you must set `count=0` in order to work.

Comment: Something like: `count=0;` and then `printCombination(arr,n,r,MEAN, count);`

Comment: @Artwo, how about the combinationUtil function, do i need to put count too?

Comment: Yes, I used wrong function, I should have used combinationUtil in my previous comment. If you want to get the count in main, you can do so by using `printCombination(..., count);`. Remember to set `count=0;` before you call the recursive function.

Comment: would you mind if i ask you to give some illustration?, i am a newbie that's why i cannot absorb all your suggestion

Comment: I will edit my original answer so you can see all the functions.

Comment: Now that I give a more deep review to your code, I notice you have some errors. And you seriously have to improve your formatting.

Comment: i already done running the program, there is no error on it, have you seen the picture that i attach? if you seen it, i just want to count all 1's there, but, the count will be back to 0